# Are there any comprehensive resources for learning Google's PlayN framework?

Tags: android, playn

How do I learn to use the [PlayN](https://developers.google.com/playn/) framework?

The [Getting Started page](https://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted) is not enough. I have been searching for some resources to learn PlayN but am unable to find any.

(P.S.: Does PlayN require GWT?)

Comment: If there are any alternatives to playn that are better documented,please recommend them.

Comment: PlayN requires GWT but isn't associaed with Google.

Answer (score 2):

http://proppy-playn101.appspot.com/#1 is a nice tutorial, but far from a complete description. An alternative to PlayN is [Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) which has become popular.

Libgdx and PlayN have the same cross-platform goals but Libgdx doesn't have Flash support, iOS support is in the works through MonoTouch (same as PlayN).

Comment: regarding libgdx, it has much more libraries bundled and has many helper utils that you won't find in playn. That's not to say playn isn't good tho, its very lean and mean, and i would say it supports html5 target better than libgdx